# Литература по bash и в целом по Linux

Tags: linux, bash, книги

Посоветуйте 1-2 книги для начального изучения Linux, желательно с акцентом изучения bash. Купил "Ubuntu и Debian Linux для продвинутых: более 1000 незаменимых команд", но она в целом расчитана на уже опытных пользователей и админов...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рекомендую цикл статей (основы Linux от основателя Gentoo):

- [Часть 1 (1/4): BASH, основы навигации](https://habrahabr.ru/post/99041/)
- [Часть 1 (2/4): Управление файлами и директориями](http://habrahabr.ru/post/99291/)
- [Часть 1 (3/4): Ссылки, а также удаление файлов и директорий](http://habrahabr.ru/post/99653/)
- [Часть 1 (4/4): Glob-подстановки](http://habrahabr.ru/post/99827/)
- [Часть 2 (1/5): Регулярные выражения](http://habrahabr.ru/post/102442/)
- [Часть 2 (2/5): Назначения папок, поиск файлов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/105495/)
- [Часть 2 (3/5): Управление процессами](http://habrahabr.ru/post/105657/)
- [Часть 2 (4/5): Обработка текста и перенаправления](http://habrahabr.ru/post/105926/)
- [Часть 2 (5/5): Модули ядра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107981/)
- [Часть 3 (1/4): Документация](http://habrahabr.ru/post/108764/)
- [Часть 3 (2/4): Модель прав доступа](http://habrahabr.ru/post/109392/)
- [Часть 3 (3/4): Управление аккаунтами в Linux](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110012/)
- [Часть 3 (4/4): Настройка пользовательского окружения](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110697/)
- [Часть 4 (1/4): Файловые системы, разделы и блочные устройства](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116907/)

Насколько я понимаю, цикл еще не закончен, но все достаточно понятно написано.

Comment: ссылками бы это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Карманный справочник по Linux Даниэла Дж. Баррета.

Answer (score 1):

Есть учебник [Runing Linux](http://books.google.ru/books?id=VKaTh_VZxcUC&pg=PA680&lpg=PA680&dq=running+linux&source=bl&ots=JXT_H-4IfJ&sig=SDLLMhHU1MttoQt633qrTVVBIjs&hl=ru&ei=PEo1TsjhAsyQswbd0_C5Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false), в 2005-ом его последний раз переиздавали и даже весьма удачно перевели на русский. Он очень большой, но там затрагиваются почти все аспекты работы в линукс, в том числе есть несколько глав про программирование на bash.

Answer (score 0):

Книги сложно советовать по-моему в современном мире.
Я бы советовала [Introduction to Linux](http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/), если с английским проблем нет, и [OpenNet](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, неплохой сайт: [рецепты Linux](http://www.linuxcookbook.ru/). [Там же](http://www.linuxcookbook.ru/books/absguide/absguide_toc.html) и хороший учебник по башу.